# What is the fastest way to increase my company's value?

Tags: railway-empire

I'm on the second campaign mission (Baltimore and Washington) and I've completed all of the campaign objectives, except the last one - increasing my company value to $20m.

Right now my company's sitting at around $11m in value, which is more than either of my competitors. While my profits are doing nicely, the value seems to be growing pretty slowly, so I'd like to know the **fastest** way of increasing this so I can move on with the campaign already. (This is assuming I'm profitable for the foreseeable, and am able to spend the bulk of my profit on investment.)

Here are the options I've considered so far:

- One of the speech bubbles advised me that my stations, trains and tracks  were primary sources of company value - so it would seem that one (slightly arduous) way of improving my value would be to builds lots more stations and trains. And I guess it's better to build new tracks, than to just pile up trains on existing ones - more tracks equals more assets.
- However, I was also pointed in the direction of buying shares in competitors; if I can get 100% (!) of their shares, I can buy them out, and presumably all of their assets then become *my* assets, which shunts (no pun intended) me closer to the $20m goal.

  This does seems attractive... but it seems like I don't get any dividends from shares less than 100%, and I'm not sure if purchased shares still count towards assets. It also seems to get quite expensive quite quickly, so I don't know if this is a viable strategy just yet.
- Also, a lot of struggling industries and companies seem to be offering for me to buy them at the moment. Should I be saving up and capitalising on these opportunities - particularly joining up my bought companies to my own stations, to maximise profit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of the above approaches seems to be the best route to success.

I found a useful display in the Company menu, which breaks down your current company value by category. Essentially everything that you buy and produce, plus all cash that you currently hold, and minus any bonds, contributes to your value - but the highest contributors for me (so far) are:

- **Businesses** - these are all places that offered me to buy them out; I then connected them up to my network and reaped the profits. I didn't bother paying towards any auctions of unprofitable businesses, but if I'd had the ready cash, this would likely have been viable too. **The value of businesses fluctuates depending on your rail network.**
- **Shares** - while buying out a competitor is indeed an expensive prospect, the *value* of my shares contributes to my company's value. So buying up shares while they're cheap is worthwhile, as those shares will increase in value along with your competitors. Whether this is better than just hanging on to the cash, I'm not sure. **The value of shares fluctuates depending on your competitor's rail networks.**
- **Buildings, Bridges, Tracks and Locomotives** (which are all related to building a rail network) are obviously the main contributors. What's interesting is that more expensive rail lines, such as those involving tunnels and bridges, contribute more than cheaper options. It goes without saying, though, that if you've got a large network, it will have a high value. **The value of these items fluctuates depending on your rail network.**
- **Cash** contributes as much as everything else - and it's handy to have a sizeable amount spare, so you can invest in any opportunities that arise - but in the long run it's better to invest it in network expansion, shares, pretty much anything that can net a profit or increase in value.

Here I am, not far off the target - just gotta pay back that bond and I'm good to go! :)

[image]